# Transfer files via ODATA

Tags: file, upload, download, odata

Is it possible to transfer files via an ODATA service? 
when there is a possibility, how could i do that?

I already searched a lot on the internet but i couldnt make it to find a proper example.

Comment: Could you list a few results that you have found during your search, and why they don't fit what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great walkthrough here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/data-services-streaming-provider-series-implementing-a-streaming-provider-part-1/ and then https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/data-services-streaming-provider-series-part-2-accessing-a-media-resource-stream-from-the-client/.

It describes a way to expose streams based on an EF provider. There's also a way to upload the stream to the server.
Note that there's nothing "OData" about the streams as such. The sample above just uses OData as the metadata for the streams and uses simple REST to get and/or upload the stream.

Comment: Both links seem to be dead. Can you provide new links?

Comment: @julealgon https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/data-services-streaming-provider-series-part-2-accessing-a-media-resource-stream-from-the-client/ and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/data-services-streaming-provider-series-implementing-a-streaming-provider-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Since you can save and retrieve binary data to/from a database and `Edm.Binary` is supported by the data model this should be possible. You could save your file in binary format in a database column and then expose it through your model and the OData API.